# New table-environment, spaces and enclosing { } in a new environment

Tags: spacing, environments, delimiters, tabu

It was hard for me to find a proper title (feel free to change it) for my question which I want to introduce with an example:

### Situation

In my document I sometimes use `tabu`s directly in the document without nesting them in a `table`-environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tabu, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
\blindtext
\\ \\
This is how I want my table to look like:

\ \\
{\centering
\begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}    \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabu}\par} \medskip \ \\
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Now, I wanted to create a new environment to help me building this table and I tried something like this:

```
\newenvironment{texttab}[1]
    {\ \\ \centering%
    \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}%
    {\end{tabu}\par \medskip \ \\}
```

where `#1` gives the `tabu`-specifications of course. It kind of works, but if you run the following MWE (adding and testing the new environment)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tabu, booktabs}

\newenvironment{texttab}[1]
    {\ \\ \centering%
    \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
    {\end{tabu}\par \medskip \ \\}

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
\blindtext
\\ \\
This is how I want my table to look like:          % no new environment

\ \\
{\centering
\begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}    \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabu}\par} \medskip \ \\
\blindtext

\begin{texttab}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}              % WITH NEW ENVIRONMENT
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

you will see that there is an indentation at the begin of the blindtext after the second table. Even adding `\noindent` into the new environment like this

```
\newenvironment{texttab}[1]
    {\ \\ \centering%
    \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
    {\end{tabu}\par \medskip \ \\ \noindent}         % added \noindent here
```

doesn't help as it still leaves some space (which I could remove with `\!\!`, but...).

This wouldn't be a problem if I could use the `{` and `}` that enclose `{\centering` and `\par}` in the very first code example.
However, I cannot put them into the definition of the new environment as this will cause delimiter-problems...
I don't want to use the `center`-environment due to unwanted vertical spaces (which seems kinda hilarious at this point of writing...)

```
\newenvironment{texttab}[1]
    {{\\centering%               % } missing!
    \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}%
    {\end{tabu}\par} \medskip \ \\}      % { missing!
```

### Questions

1. **Is there a way to, either, get rid of those "uncontrollable spaces" that appear in the running version, or, make the last piece
   of code workable?** (I don't want to use a `minipage` here, as I
   maybe want to make it breakable with `longtabu`.)
2. Then, sticking with the (for now) working "new environment": Why
   doesn't

   ```
   \newenvironment{texttab}[2]
       {\ \\ \centering%
       \begin{#1tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#2} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
       {\end{#1tabu}\par \medskip \ \\}
   ```

   work, so that I could easily change the `tabu` into a `longtabu` by
   setting the first argument `long`?
3. Should I rather try to pack all this into a new *command* with several
   arguments?
4. Do you think that maybe the whole idea is...stupid?

Comment: You should, first of all, avoid the clumsy ``\ \\`` construction for leaving vertical space; `\par\medskip` is surely better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that keeping it simple is better. `;-)`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tabu, booktabs}

\newenvironment{texttab}[1]
  {\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
  {\end{tabu}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
This is how I want my table to look like:          % no new environment
\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}    \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\blindtext
\begin{texttab}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}              % WITH NEW ENVIRONMENT
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

In order to control the vertical spacing above and below the table, modify the value of `\topsep`, rather than using `\\` (which should *never* be used to “leave blank lines”). I used `\topsep=\baselineskip`, change it to suit your needs; I'd not even set it, to be honest, so using the default value.

[image]

You can solve your second problem by defining

```
\newenvironment{texttab}[2][]
  {\def\longornot{#1}\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
   \begin{center}
   \begin{#1tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#2} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
  {\expandafter\end\expandafter{\longornot tabu}\end{center}}
```

so that you can say

```
\begin{texttab}[long]{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
...
\end{texttab}
```

but I'd prefer defining a different environment, say

```
\newenvironment{texttab*}[1]
  {\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
   \begin{center}
   \begin{longtabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
  {\end{longtabu}\end{center}}
```

The problem was that you can't use `#1` in the final argument to `\newenvironment`. Take your pick.

Comment: Thank you for the topsep-command - I don't know why I didn't stumble over that so far... (It does affect the space above and below the environment, right?) | ad Nr. 1: I just found out that the delimiter-problem could very well be solved with \begingroup and \endgroup, is that right? | Would \centering be in any way preferable to center in this particular case (as I use \centering in table-environments)? | If you have any idea about the question Nr. 2 I'd like to accept your answer!

Comment: @LCsa You could solve question #2, in an indirect way, but I suggest you to use a different environment, such as `texttab*`. I'll add it.

Comment: Thank you, @egreg, I will now try to understand the solution you provided, but it's...hard for me. xD

Is there a special reason why you recommend using a different environment?

Comment: May I link here to a follow-up-question? Thanks.
[Vertical Spaces above and below longtabu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115180/vertical-spaces-above-and-below-longtabu)