# Vertical spaces above and below longtabu

Tags: spacing, environments, longtable, tabu

This is, in a way, a follow-up-question to [New table-environment, spaces and enclosing { } in a new environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114964/new-table-environment-spaces-and-enclosing-in-a-new-environment), which has already been answered conveniently by @egreg.

---

Please compile this MWE to see and follow the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\usepackage{tabu, longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\newenvironment{texttab}[1]%
        {\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
            \begin{center} \tabulinesep=0.6ex%
            \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
            {\end{tabu}%
        \end{center}}

\newenvironment{tabspaces}[1]%
    {\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
        \begin{center} \tabulinesep=0.6ex%
            \begin{longtabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
            {\end{longtabu}%
        \end{center}}

\newenvironment{texttab*}[1]%
    {\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
    \LTpre=0pt%
    \LTpost=0pt%
        \begin{center} \tabulinesep=0.6ex%
            \begin{longtabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
            {\end{longtabu}%
        \end{center}}

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
\blindtext
%
\begin{texttab}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{tabspaces}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabspaces}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{texttab*}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab*}%
%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

I created three new environments: `texttab`, `tabspaces` and `texttab*`.
They implement `tabu`s (not to be embedded in floating bodies) in the text.
As a result of the question mentioned before I made two environments for either normal `tabu`s (`texttab`) or `longtabu`s (`texttab*`). `tabspaces` is just for demonstration-use.

Now, if you take a look at the `tabspaces`-environment (second table in the example), you see it produces **way too much vertical space above and below** the environment.

I tried to use the commands `\LTpre=0pt` and `\LTpost=0pt`(provided by the `longtable`-package) in the `texttab*`-environment - you see, there's still way too much space below!

**Where does it come from and how do I get rid of it?**

*Note:* `\tabulinesep=0.6ex` seems to affect those spaces! Nevertheless, removing it doesn't change the fact that the vertical spaces still differ from the ones in my (satisfying) `texttab`-environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why setting `\LTpre` and `\LTpost` has no effect on the `texttab*` environment is because you reset them to `0pt` in the definition of that environment.  I removed those two lines and set some rough values globally that give similar spacing to that produced by `texttab`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\usepackage{tabu, longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}\setlength{\LTpost}{-17pt}%

\newenvironment{texttab}[1]%
        {\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
            \begin{center} \tabulinesep=0.6ex%
            \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
            {\end{tabu}%
        \end{center}}

\newenvironment{tabspaces}[1]%
    {\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
        \begin{center} \tabulinesep=0.6ex%
            \begin{longtabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
            {\end{longtabu}%
        \end{center}}

\newenvironment{texttab*}[1]%
    {\setlength{\topsep}{\baselineskip}%
        \begin{center} \tabulinesep=0.6ex%
            \begin{longtabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
            {\end{longtabu}%
        \end{center}}

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
\blindtext
%
\begin{texttab}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{tabspaces}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabspaces}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{texttab*}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab*}%
%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

---

Qrrbrbirlbel points out below that using `\centering` rather than the `center` environment is an option.  My quick attempt is below.  I did a bit of fiddling with `\par`'s to avoid the lines above from being centered as well...I'm not sure if there's a better way to go about doing that.  In any case, because of the different behaviour of `tabu` and `longtabu` I think you may have to fiddle with the spacing of the first environment to match the latter two or vice-versa.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}

\usepackage{tabu, longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\newenvironment{texttab}[1]%
    {\par\bigskip\centering\tabulinesep=0.6ex%
     \begin{tabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
    {\end{tabu}\par\bigskip}

\newenvironment{tabspaces}[1]%
    {\par\centering\tabulinesep=0.6ex%
     \begin{longtabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
    {\end{longtabu}}

\newenvironment{texttab*}[1]%
    {\par\centering\tabulinesep=0.6ex%
     \begin{longtabu} to 0.9\textwidth {#1} \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}}
    {\end{longtabu}}

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
\blindtext

\begin{texttab}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3 works fine  \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab}%

\blindtext
%
\begin{tabspaces}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabspaces}%
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{texttab*}{X[l,2] X[l,2] X[l,3]}
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \midrule
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\
Test1   &   Test2   &   Test3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{texttab*}%
%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much!

There remains a little question, though: How is it that one has to set '\LTpost=-17pt'? Why isn't "=0pt" that eliminates all space and, furthermore, how did you figure out it should be '-17pt' to serve its purpose?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: No problem!  Unfortunately, I don't know what specifically it is about `longtabu/longtable` that causes the extra spacing.  I assume that it is a consequence of the ability to split a table across pages.  The `-17pt` was simply from guess and check...I tried `-15pt` and it wasn't enough while `-20pt` was too much.  I'm not sure if it's exact, but it looked close enough to me.

Comment: Haha, I see - and thought so, because I tried to check all possible lengths and heights with 'printlen' and so forth... :P
Maybe I'll find a way to work "exact", you know what I mean. But until then, I'm glad you came up with your answer (which is now accepted). :)

Comment: I don’t exactly know for what those length are, but it seems as if the combination with the `center` environment introduces one empty line (besides the usual vertical space from the `center` environment). Setting the post length to `-\baselineskip` produces a satisfying result (IMO). Maybe it is better to not use the `center` environment and the macro `\centering` instead with properly set pre and post lengths?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That's a good suggestion, I didn't consider that the center environment might have something to do with it.  Would you like to add an answer or should I update mine to include that option?

Comment: How do I use the `\centering` command in the `\newenvironment`? Just putting it into the begin-code of `\newenvironment` does _not_ produce the desired layout. Also, I tried a very... banal way of figuring out the lengths while putting your suggestion, @Qrrbrbirlbel, into practice (`-\baselineskip` post length): I made a screenshot, pasted it into paint, and drew lines pixel by pixel between several reference points. **Result:** `texttab` 19pt above and below. `texttab*` 18pt above and 23 below...

Comment: With the usage of `\centering` instead of the `center`-environment not all of the spaces do vanish. So, it seems that `longtable` itself inserts some space (which can be corrected with `\LTpre=1pt` and `\LTpost=-3pt`). As far as I know one has to insert `\par\centering` before the rest of the code and `\par\noindent` afterwards in order to make it work correctly. But then `\topsep` has no effect anymore! **Why?** Also: There is a _little_ indent after the first one of the two tables when proceeding as described. **Why?**
If you, @ScottH., include these suggestions (and answers) it'd be great.